# Mapeando a memória da placa de vídeo para acesso via processador x86 Intel compatible

Tags: assembly, intel, x86, gráfico

Pensando em computadores x86 Intel compatible, sem considerar as facilidades fornecidas pelos sistemas operacionais modernos, quem quiser desenhar/escrever algo na tela do computador pode acessar alguns endereços conhecidos, como B800:0000 (B8000h linear), A000:0000 (A0000h linear) etc, e através deles consegue escrever caracteres ou pixels na tela.

Contudo, pensando apenas em pixels, o endereço A0000h mapeia uma região muito pequena da memória de vídeo (128k), muito longe da capacidade das placas de vídeo atuais.

Além disso, utilizando apenas as rotinas básicas fornecidas pelo padrão VGA e SVGA, não se consegue alterar a resolução para, por exemplo 1366 x 768 (pelo menos não pude identificar como).

A pergunta é, supondo que eu já esteja executando em modo protegido 32 ou 64 bits, no ring0, como fazer para mapear uma região da memória de vídeo para que o processador possa acessá-la, e como configurar a placa de vídeo para resoluções superiores a 800 x 600?

Com relação ao mapeamento de memória, isso deve ser feito em alguma entrada da GDT?

Sei que o Linux é open source, mas o código é grande, e não tenho muita experiência com ele. Se a reposta envolver o código fonte do Linux, eu pediria, por favor, para indicar a versão, o arquivo e as linhas correspondentes.

Comment: Utilizar o framebuffer seria uma opção para você?

Comment: Sim, seria uma solução válida, desde que eu conseguisse mapear uma região grande da memória da placa de vídeo. Por exemplo, para uma placa com 256MB, seria legal conseguir acessar esses 256MB. Na pior das hipóteses, gostaria pelo menos de conseguir mapear memória suficiente para fazer um *double buffer*: em uma resolução de 1366x768 @ 32bpp, gostaria de mapear, pelo menos, (1366 × 768 × 4) × 2 bytes.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente apenas escrevi para o framebuffer então não consigo responder a pergunta, mas achei dois artigos interessantes que podem ajudar: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/  e  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt  
Se achar uma resposta você mesmo pode responder sua pergunta (isto é válido e encorajado pelo stackexchange).

Comment: Opa, valeu Pablo! Vou analisar os links agora :) Estou em outros projetos, e esse do acesso direto ao framebuffer não tem grande prioridade... Se eu conseguir fazer algo, pode deixar que posto a resposta ;)

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar a memória da placa não são estes endereços, este processo envolve o acesso direto à placa de vídeo através de "interrupções de hardware", você chamaria em seu assembly:

```
int 0x00 ; o número passado é um código interno para uma função de hardware
```

e este comando por exemplo passaria dados da memória RAM para Placa de vídeo ou vice-versa ou ainda chamaria comandos internos da mesma.

"sinceramente não sei como este processo funciona especificamente devido os Drivers do fabricante, bibliotecas como DirectX, DXGI e OpenGL fazerem todo o trabalho."

Comment: Na verdade as interrupções de software são definidas pela BIOS durante o boot. Cada sistema operacional tem a liberdade para depois alterar seu código. Por exemplo, a `int 10h`, que é a interrupção para acessar serviços de vídeo no DOS (e em outros sistemas operacionais que dependem 100% da BIOS - [ver aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H)). Os endereços da pergunta são usados para acesso direto à memória em modos de vídeo básicos, como 320x240 @ 8bpp, ou em modo de texto. O que eu procuro está mais na linha do comentário do Pablo.